# _InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic> firestore error in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, maps, hybrid-mobile-app

I have set up Cloud Firestore as my database and am retrieving a document, with maps, here is a snapshot:

[image]

When I try to retrieve the document with `get()`, I get a `DocumentSnapshot`, which I then convert to a `Map<String, dynamic>`, this consists, numerous nested maps, like in the image above. So I iterate over them with `.forEach`, and I successfully receive the values (checked with breakpoints).

Now because I want to show them in my UI, I store all the **nested maps** in a `List()` but when I try to add them, I get this error:

**Log:**
`type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast`

**Code:**

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> dummyListMap = new List();

await docRef.get().then((value) {
      value.data.forEach((key, mapValue) {
        dummyListMap.add(mapValue as Map<String, dynamic>);
      });
    });
```

There are a few questions on StackOverflow with the same error, but they are about JSON data structures, and I could not decode them to use it for my case.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert the `_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>` to a `Map<String, dynamic>`. By using `forEach` you are splitting the key and value of the `DocumentSnapshot`. Everything is fine up until this point. Now the value has a type of `_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>`. You would have to convert it to a `Map<String, dynamic>`.

Replace your code with this:

```
dummyListMap.add(Map<String,dynamic>.from(mapValue));
```

Comment: yep, works like a charm! Thanks a lot, I asked a trivial question

Comment: I got `The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'.`

Comment: you have to pass a type `_InternalLinkedHashMap` to `Map<String,dynamic>.from`. If you're sure that the type of the Object is a `_InternalLinkedHashMap` you can convert it like this `object as  _InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>`